# Understanding weak maps

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, weakmap

ECMAScript 6 introduces weak maps, available in Node.JS v0.11.3 with the `--harmony` flag. Consider the following.

```
let weakMap = WeakMap();
let key = [];
let rubbish = 'fish cans';

weakMap.set(key, rubbish);
rubbish = 'empty bottle';

// Prints "fish cans"
console.log(weakMap.get(key));
```

I was under the impression that, for weak maps, the reference from the key to the value is *weak*, so that if the only reference to the value is the key, then the value can no longer be accessed.

Why then is the value `'fish cans'` still accessible and not garbage collected? The variable `rubbish` no longer references it, and the reference from `key` to `'fish cans'` is *weak*, i.e. non-existant from the point of view of the garbage collector. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing that the value *still* can be accessed just because the garbage guy didn't pass by the street yet. In other words, maybe if you were to try that some time after it wouldn't work?

Comment: A way to check if that's the case would be to run a sadistic loop of allocations where the engine would be forced to GC stuff up. If it's still there, then something's holding it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The weak part is about the keys, not the values. From the current draft:

> WeakMap are intended to provide a mechanism for dynamically associating state with an object in a manner that does not “leak” memory resources if, in the absence of the WeakMap, the object otherwise became inaccessible and subject to resource reclamation by the implementation’s garbage collection mechanisms.

Say you have a DOM element and want to associate some data with it and use a `WeakMap` for that: `weakMap.set(domElement, data);`. When the DOM element gets deleted then the entry in the weak map gets deleted too.

On the other hand you would not want the data to be deleted as long the DOM element exists, just because there is no other reference to it outside the weak map.

Apart from that `'fish cans'` is a primitive type and as such not subject to the garbage collection.

Answer (score 12):

> Why then is the value `'fish cans'` still accessible and not garbage collected? The variable rubbish no longer references it, and the reference from key to `'fish cans'` is weak, i.e. non-existant from the point of view of the garbage collector. What am I missing?

The variable `rubbish` never was the one that needed to reference it. The association (reference) from the key to the value still exists as long as the key is not collected. The weak reference, which the GC cannot see, is the one from the map to the key/value pair (the one which would make the map enumerable). Yet your `key` still exists, and you can get every value that you stored for it in the map:

```
var map = WeakMap(),
    key = [];

map.set(key, 'fish cans');
console.log(map.get(key)); // Prints "fish cans"
```

To demonstrate the weakness, you'd have to use the following:

```
var map = WeakMap(),
    key = [];

map.set(key, 'fish cans');
// map.size == 1
key = null;
// map.size == 0 - the fish cans got garbage-collected together with the key
map.get(???) // impossible now
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand this as well. I think the paragraph said like:

```
var key={a:1};
var wm=new WeakMap();


wm.set(key,"value");
wm.get(key); //you can get "value";

key=undefined;
console.log(wm.get(key));//error.original key have no longer existed. so "value" is not longer existed as well.
```

Due to WeakMap has no way to retrieve the keys, you have no way to get that "value" any more.

if we use Map(), due to has keys(),entries(), although the variable key lost reference, "value" still can be retrieved.

```
var key={a:1};
var m=new Map();


m.set(key,"value");
console.log(m.keys().next());; //you can get "value";

key=undefined;
console.log(m.get(m.keys().next().value));//you can get "value";
```

**Conclusion:**

If object key of **WeakMap** have lost its reference, this key and value will be garbage collected as well(because logically inaccessible). This way can prevent memory leak.

If object key  of **Map** have lost its reference, this key and value will be still available until you deleted or cleared. So you need to be aware of memory leak during development

Just find a link about understanding weakmap and its use-cases:
http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/02/what-are-weakmaps-in-es6/

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to address/clarify the following point:

The initial value of the variable '`rubbish`' was never mutated; all you accomplished on `rubbish = 'empty bottle';` was to associate the **alias** `rubbish` to a different value. Hence even after `rubbish = 'empty bottle';` was executed, the `weakMap` entry with key '`key`' still has a value associated with it that references the original value of `rubbish`.

Then to make the value lose its association with the key, you should *change* value of the key variable (as already noted in @Bergi's answer).

Note that `key.push("whatever");` does not amount to a *change*. However, `key = [];` repeated again would do as well as `key = null;`. Generally, any reassignment will amount to the desired change.